# Need help with boost converter for solenoid

Tags: bjt, boost, zener, solenoid

I have a pull-solenoid with 32 ohms of resistance. I would like to supply 1 Amp to it with a 1 cell lipo battery: 3.7v nominal, 15 amp draw, 720mah. The power draw only needs to last for a fraction of a second to actuate the piston on the solenoid.

Using pspice I found that charging the solenoid by itself and then opening a switch to force the current through a zener diode forced the voltage to rise to the breakdown voltage of the zener because of flyback effect from the inductor. I then tried to use a TIP102 to allow a path for the 1 amp to flow but have had no luck.

With the TIP102 in the circuit, the voltage on the zener doesn't spike nearly as high and the current into the base is less than before the switch opens and little current enters the collector.

**Battery through inductor with switch opening after 1us. When the switch opens, the voltage across the inductor increases until it reaches the breakdown voltage of the zener, in this case 30V. This is shown correct in pspice sim. The theory here is the inductor will create enough voltage potential in the circuit to pull an amp through itself.**
[image]

**When the flyback voltage rises to the breakdown voltage, current enters the base of the TIP102 and a large amount of current can flow into the collector**

[image]

- Edited for more explanation

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to get a current of 1A through that solenoid? You need 32V to do that. And with that kind of circuit you won't ever get that (the maximum current is 3.7V / 32 Ohm, around 120 mA). You need a boost converter in front of your solenoid to get 32V (which then uses another inductor). And what's with the switch and the zener diode? Did you maybe mix up the idea of a boost converter and placed your load (which happens to be an inductor) as the inductor in the boost converter?

Answer (score 2):

You will need a boost converter that takes your ~3 volt battery and boosts it to 32 volts. Your solenoid will then draw 1 amp from the 32 volt supply.

You should anticipate though, that your battery will not last very long. The boost converter will draw ~10 amps from your battery so its life between charges will be measured in minutes.

Comment: You could potentially use the solenoid as the inductor in a boost configuration, controlling the switch duty cycle to regulate the current to 1A, or controlling the voltage to get the 1A.

Comment: JohnD This won't work because the max current through the inductor is limited by the 'R' value. With a LiPo @ 3.7 V you can only get 115 mA. With this you could charge a capacitor bank to 32 V, but the solenoid would not be activated at this time. There would be no way to start/hold the solenoid activation using this method. Simple math tells you that to get 1 A you need 32 V --> 32 W for continuous activation. 32 W @3.7 V is  8.6 A minimum from the battery.

Comment: @JackCreasey quite right if he needs continuous activation, but with a half bridge on one end of the inductor (the battery end) you could dump the energy you stored in the cap bank into the solenoid and get it to actuate.  I think.  I got the impression from the schemes the OP was trying that the solenoid might not need to be actuated for long.  Could be wrong though.

Comment: I'm trying to use the solenoid itself as the flyback inductor, that's why there's only one series circuit here. It should create it's own voltage potential to pull the current from the battery.
Also to note, since it's a pull-solenoid, I only need the power draw for a fraction of a second to pull the piston in, then it will release and the spring will actuate something else.

Answer (score 0):

The classic approach is to charge a capacitor bank.  You will need a big enough bank to provide the 1 amp for enough time to shift the solenoid, which is dependent on the load and the stroke, but usually tens of milliseconds.  There are many IC's available to charge capacitors, designed for flashes in cameras.

Once you have shifted the solenoid, you will require much less current to hold it in place, and probably can use the battery voltage directly.  You will need to experiment with the hold current to see if the battery voltage is sufficient to hold your load once it is pulled in.

If you use this approach, you will greatly increase your battery life, but keep in mind that you will need time to re-charge the capacitor bank between actuations.  If you use the boost converter as @Glenn W9IQ suggests, you can still drop the voltage to a lower level while holding the solenoid closed so you won't kill your battery so quickly, but your battery would have to deliver the 10 amps during pull-in.  By charging the cap bank, you can reduce the instantaneous battery current.